# What is [background]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

[background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/background) seems to be used for three different things -

- UI element background color
- Background Activities in android
- Starting a process in or moving a process into the back ground

It's a confusingly broad tag, but there are currently 9,179 questions using this tag.  What should we do about this?